# thumbnail taskbar windows preview X my app topmost

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have an 'issue'... my app is a simple winform C# 4.0 with topmost set as true. It's like a stamp (watermark) always showing the user logged + datetime in the foreground. But when the user passes the mouse with the thumbnail preview my app gets to the back and disappear the info needed for the company is the user tries to print some confidential doc and sending it to others... I know there's a way to disable (https://www.thewindowsclub.com/tenable-or-disable-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-in-windows-10) the thumbail preview but the client dont accept it because it'll affect the user experience... Do you know if there's some win api to solve this? keeping my app always in foreground... TKS!

I tried to put a new piece of code -> a timer every second with the code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActivateApp("Stamp.NetCore");
    SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
}

void ActivateApp(string processName)
{
    Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

    // Activate the first application we find with this name
    if (p.Count() > 0)
    {        
        SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
    }                
}
```

but no sucess! when the user passes the mouse over the thumbnail preview my app goes to the back

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can i upload the solution?